# TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE no guarda la hora del lado del cliente Oracle, Spring Boot y Angular

Tags: java, oracle, spring, angular7

No logró guardar correctamente la hora del cliente.
He programado un trigger sobre las horas habiles y se ejecuta correctamente en la base de datos, pero hay un defase de la zona horaria.

Se envia mediante el controlador la hora 8:00 am
[image: Envio de hora: 8:00 am]

Se guarda 3:00 am
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es preferible postear el código en vez de imágenes. Te invito a leer [ask]. En cuanto a tu pregunta, tal vez debas repasar TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE y aclarar las dudas en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169). Según lo que puedo ver en tu código, el valor del TIMESTAMP se está guardando en la BD de la forma correcta. Saludos